# Showing an algebra separates points

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces. Show the algebra generated by functions of the form $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$, where $g \in C(X)$ and $h \in C(Y)$ is dense in $C(X \times Y)$

Call the algebra described above as $A$. I already know that $X \times Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space using Tychonoff's Theorem, and that $A$ contains all constant functions. So in order to use the Stone-Weirestrass theorem to conclude that $A$ is dense in $C(X \times Y)$, all I need to show is that $A$ separates points.

So define two points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ so that $(a,b) \neq (c,d)$. Then either $a \neq c$ or $b \neq d$. I'm at a loss as to how to pick a function $f(x,y)$ so that $f(a,b) \neq f(c,d)$ In one dimension, it seemed like the identity function $f(x) = x$ gives a solution, but I can't think of how to extend this to a two dimensional function since it seems like $f$ is supposed to map $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $a\ne c$, choose a $g\in C(X)$ that separates $a$ and $c$, and choose a constant $h\in C(Y)$.

Comment: If $a \neq c$ then I could easily pick $g(x) = x$ and $h(y) = 1$. Likewise, if $b \neq d$, then pick $g(x) = 1$ and $h(y) = y$. But then it seems like I have two functions rather than 1? I thought I was supposed to find one function $f$ so that $f(a,b) \neq f(c,d)$, whereas here, I have two functions depending on if $a \neq c$ or $b \neq d$

Comment: @Brenton: Look at the definition of $A$: each member of it is a product of a function on $X$ and a function on $Y$.

Comment: Sure, so it seems like taking $f(x,y)$ to be the product of $g(x) = x \forall x \in X$ and $h(y) = 1 \forall y \in Y$ when $a \neq c$ works for that case. I'm not understanding how the definition of $A$ shows there is one $f$ that works for both cases.

Comment: @Brenton: You don’t need (and can’t necessarily get) a single function that works for both cases. You just have to show that for any pair of distinct points of $X\times Y$ there is an $f\in A$ that separates them.

Comment: Ok that makes things easier then. So I can just suppose without loss of generality that $a \neq c$ and then pick the identity function for $g$ and a constant for $h$, and then that should solve the problem?

Comment: @Brenton: If this is for coursework, I would explicitly cover both cases ($a\ne c$ and $b\ne d$, and you do want to specify that the constant value for $h$ isn’t $0$, but other than that, yes.

Comment: Ok great, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Brenton: You’re very welcome!